# What is the difference between EffectComposer & NodePostProcessing in Threejs?

Tags: three.js

It appears that both of these are supposed to chain post processing effects during rendering. But I don't understand how they differ or why you would use one over another.

The Threejs docs has a [sparse post processing page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-use-post-processing) but it never mentions anything about nodes despite several post processing examples using them.

Ultimately what I am interested in doing is similar to this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=post#webgl_postprocessing_nodes) except I'd also like to add sharpening as well. But I can find zero documentation about the "Nodes" that are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node material in `three.js` is experimental and thus not documented. If you want to do post processing with `three.js`, it's best to stick to `EffectComposer` and its respective examples. Almost all documentation, tutorials or post processing demos you find online are based on `EffectComposer`.